# CorePlot ScatterPlot scrolling performance iPhone4

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics, core-plot

I am using core plot to draw graphs. So far it seems to be a great framework but I have encountered some performance issues when I enable user interaction and perform a scroll.

At first I thought this was due to the number of points being plotted so I wrote a simple test app with very few points. Scrolling was still quite jerky despite the plot being as simple as possible. I get around 20-25 fps on an iPhone 4 with this plot.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just as fast as it gets with core plot?

My sample code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    graph = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length: CPTDecimalFromDouble(5)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5)];
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-10) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(100)];
    plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-10) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(20)];

    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:30];

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0);
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:30];

    // Create a plot that uses the data source method
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"1";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.f;
    lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor redColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    dataSourceLinePlot.delegate = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return 20;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its best if you perform plotting in the background.

You are probably trying to plot/process these graphs on the main queue which is bad. What is happening is all your rendering, processing and your user touch events are all being backed up on the main queue,like below. So what you are getting is the plotting, processing and touch events are happening in the order they are being received (FIFO). If you put the processing on the background touch events will be handled without waiting.  (Please watch the video referenced below)

```
BAD (what you are probably doing)
MainQueue: Process/Plot -> TouchEvent(scroll) -> Render -> Plot/Process -> Plot/Process -> TouchEvent(scroll) -> Update UI -> TouchEvent

GOOD
MainQueue: TouchEvent(scroll) -> TouchEvent(scroll) -> Update UI -> TouchEvent
ProcessingQueue: Process/Plot -> Plot/Process -> Plot/Process
```

Its best to let the MainQueue only handle rendering (UI updates) and touch events and put everything else on background queues.

```
NSOperationQueue *q = [NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[q setName:@"Plotting Queue"];
[q addOperationWithBlock:^{ plotGraph(); }];
[q addOperationWithBlock:^{ 
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        updateTheUI();
     }];
}];
```

**plotGraph** method would be all your plotting code above.
**updateTheUI** method would be your hostView.hostedGraph = graph; line plus any code to make the UI re-render itself.

Check out WWDC 2012 video called **"Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS"**

Comment: The plot delegate is initially called when the graph loads the first time. It is not called on every subsequent reload or user interaction. When scrolling occurs I believe the only thing being done by the CorePlot framework is rendering. I'm not really doing any background tasks as such it is all rendering related so I don' think your suggestion applies here but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You will probably need to move the drawing to the background, as well. What kind of viewController is holding these plots? ScrollView, TableView or ?

Comment: Also you best bet is to use the Time Profiler to see what is spiking.

Comment: I'll check the profiler to see whats taking time, if it is drawing I don't see how moving this to another thread will help? It will still take just as long. As I am using CorePlot the way that the samples indicate, I was more wondering if this is a known CorePlot issue.

Comment: It might help if you watch the video mentioned above. The length of time does matter. Queues do matter. If you a drawing, plotting, and handling events all on the main queue then you can't handle user scrolling. Think about it as a line of people waiting at butcher (take a number). You handle #1, then #2, then #3. So if scroll event is #3 (user scrolled) then nothing will happen until those in front of it, in line, are handled first. The scroll event waits in the queue until its number is called. In your case #1 and #2 are big orders (steak for 4,000 people) you might end up waiting forever.

Answer (score 0):

I had huge performance problems with my scatter plot until I set the axis labeling policies.  Setting the labeling policy to either Automatic or None eliminated 5 seconds of lag I was having.

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

Comment: I need the axis labels unfortunately. Removing them yields a slight performance improvement but not much.